# Publishing to SQS from a whitelisted IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs

Is there any way an application can post messages to a SQS queue by being *whitelisted* by its machine IP address?

I took a look at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-restrict-calls-ip-addresses/ but this is for a role and I'd still need an AWS user to do this.

Is there any way to publish to a SQS queue just from an IP address, without needing an AWS user at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that for SQS (not SNS) I can do this with whitelists the ip of the sender. Then I can just do a POST and it will work.

Comment: Can you please share where you found this information?

Comment: @oneworld I tested this myself, had to add a whitelisting policy

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct way - you still need your AWS credentials.

But another way would be to have an AWS API Gateway that calls a Lambda that sends the SQS message.  The API Gateway would be restricted to a small (or one) set of IP's.  [This link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-resource-policy-access/) goes into details but the key is having a resource policy on your API gateway call:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "execute-api:/*/*/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "execute-api:/*/*/*",
      "Condition": {
        "NotIpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": ["1.2.3.4"]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

where `1.2.3.4` is the IP address you want to allow in.  This API Gateway call would then call your Lambda.  Internally you're still using IAM roles but external to AWS you're not.

Answer (score 0):

If your application runs in a VPC you can use AWS PrivateLink to connect to your SQS queue privately so traffic does not traverse the internet, this normally resolves the need to whitelist an IP address for internal private traffic. [SQS and AWS PrivateLink](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/12/amazon-sqs-vpc-endpoints-aws-privatelink/)